# same version number for different builds in App stores

Tags: android

I have uploaded android build to google play and I have IOS build pending

Answer (score 2):

Use the version name for what you want users to see. Increment the version code to upload new apks.

> **versionCode** — A positive integer used as an internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number is set by the **versionName** setting, below. The Android system uses the versionCode value to protect against downgrades by preventing users from installing an APK with a lower versionCode than the version currently installed on their device.

[Version your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)

Comment: ThankYou Ahmed. Users already installed version name 4.10 will get update again if I add a new apk with version name 4.10. Please advise

Comment: If the version code of the new APK is higher, they should get the new one as an update.

Answer (score 0):

VersionName can be anything and is not compared to previous names, so same version name but a new APK with new version code is downloaded by user and installed as upgrade.

Comment: Ahmed & AIMIN, now I upgraded version code and kept same version name but in Release Dashboard I see my version name with (2). Example : 1.0.0(2) Will there be any change I see when i release the version into App Store? Please advise.